# How to show specific text based on page path using a php function

Tags: php, html, url, web

I am using on a multipage website built in php that uses a global footer in  its own blade. 
When a page blade loads in content for the body, it calls upon the global footer blade to import content for the footer. This way I only need to make changes in the global footer blade instead of every page.

Want I want to do now, is to create a conditional statement in my footer that allows me to load content depending on the page path.

#### For example

```
animals.com/foxes/basics
```

Should load in content in the footer about foxes.

```
animals.com/bears/info
```

Should load in content in the footer about bears.

This info is based on the path having bears vs foxes and affects all child pages in that path.

Any advice on how to get started with using a PHP conditional that looks at the path in a URL or site? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into `$_SERVER` and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Read about STRATEGY design pattern. Input should be your URL( if you want to base on that) output could be the path to your footer file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the URI. For example, index.php.